# Get Weather status of multiple locations inside for loop android

Tags: java, android, location, okhttp, weather-api

I am developing a weather app for that I am using dark sky API in which I want to know the weather status of a bunch of locations which I have stored in `ArrayList<LatLng>`.

I am using `OKHttp` to parse the JSON data from API, so I tried to loop the whole fetching process inside for loop but it doesn't give the desired output.

```
private void beginTask(ArrayList<LatLng> arrayLis) { 
    //arraylis contains list of locations(LatLng)
    m = 0;
    startTask = true;

    for (int i = 0;i<arrayLis.size();i++) {
        double latitude = ((LatLng)arrayLis.get(i)).latitude;
        double longitude = ((LatLng)arrayLis.get(i)).longitude;
        String url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/"
                +latitude+","+longitude+"?units=si";
        LatLng mylatlng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
        startProcess(url,mylatlng);

        Log.i("GGGTT",""+latitude+", "+longitude);
    }
}

private void startProcess(String myurl, final LatLng myLatlng){
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(myurl)
            .build();

    Call call  = httpClient.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String data = response.body().string();
            Log.i("DATASS",data);
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                try {
                    getCurrentDetails(data,myLatlng);
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void getCurrentDetails(String data,LatLng myLatlng) throws JSONException{
    JSONObject main = new JSONObject(data);
    double la = main.getDouble("latitude");
    double lon = main.getDouble("longitude");
    JSONObject currently = main.getJSONObject("currently");
    String summary = currently.getString("summary");
    double temperature = currently.getDouble("temperature");
    String icon = currently.getString("icon");

    LatLng latLngo = new LatLng(la,lon);
    ter.add(latLngo);
    weatherInfo.add(icon);

    // Output here is not in the same order that I have passed 

    Log.i("LETSCHECK",""+la+", "+lon +icon);
}
```

I am passing the values as:

1. 19.21111,73.07729
2. 19.20238,73.06582
3. 19.19383,73.05362
4. 19.18848,73.04221

But the output is not in the same order inside the `getCurrentDetails` method

1. 19.19383,73.05362
2. 19.20238,73.06582
3. 19.18848,73.04221
4. 19.21111,73.07729

I think the method is not waiting before the previous loop gets completed.

Are there any solutions for getting the weather status of all locations stored in `ArrayList` without changing its order?

**EDIT**

Hi, I have gone through this method to fetch data in order and its working fine, thanks but one more problem is that I was expecting to show data 4 times as there are four LatLngs in ArrayList and it's working fine, but when I try to read the fetching data that I have stored in another array it only shows 2 items rather than 4.

```
private void getCurrentDetails(String data,LatLng myLatlng) throws JSONException{

    JSONObject main = new JSONObject(data);
    double la = main.getDouble("latitude");
    double lon = main.getDouble("longitude");
    JSONObject currently = main.getJSONObject("currently");
    String summary = currently.getString("summary");
    double temperature = currently.getDouble("temperature");
    String icon = currently.getString("icon");

    //Log.i("LETSCHECK",""+la+", "+lon +icon+",k");

    loopi++;
    Log.i("LETSCHECK",""+loopi);
    if (loopi < arrayList.size()) {
        getItAgain();
    } else if (loopi == arrayList.size()){
        for (String l:weatherInfo){
            Log.i("LETSCHECK",l); 
            //expected 4 items to show but its showing only 2 items
        }
    }

    Log.i("LETSCHECK",""+la+", "+lon +icon);
    weatherInfo.add(icon); 
}

private void getItAgain() {
    double latitude = ((LatLng)arrayList.get(loopi)).latitude;
    double longitude = ((LatLng)arrayList.get(loopi)).longitude;
    String url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/74d8feeda5ecf5ee6667d034778b239d/"
            +latitude+","+longitude+"?units=si";
    LatLng mylatlng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    startProcess(url,mylatlng);
}
```

Comment: This happen because of the network call is async. What you can do is without calling inside the for loop you can do a network call one by one. If the first network call finish remove the element from the array and do a next network call.

Comment: @IshanFernando Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. If you don't mind can you please give me a sample code that can help me. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network calls are asynchronous and this the expected behavior that you are having here. If you want to get them sorted as you have passed them, then you might need to have a mechanism of waiting for the network call of the previous one to be completed and then again call the next one. However, this might increase the delay of waiting for the response from the server, as you are not fetching multiple responses from the server concurrently.

If you want to wait for the response to maintain the sorted manner, you might just need to do the following.

```
// Declare a global variable of the list of your locations. 
ArrayList<LatLng> arrayLis; 
int i = 0; 

// Just start the first task without the loop. 
double latitude = ((LatLng)arrayLis.get(i)).latitude;
double longitude = ((LatLng)arrayLis.get(i)).longitude;
String url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/"
        +latitude+","+longitude+"?units=si";
LatLng mylatlng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
startProcess(url,mylatlng);
```

Now in the `getCurrentDetails` function, you might just have to do the following.

```
private void getCurrentDetails(String data,LatLng myLatlng) throws JSONException{
    JSONObject main = new JSONObject(data);
    double la = main.getDouble("latitude");
    double lon = main.getDouble("longitude");
    JSONObject currently = main.getJSONObject("currently");
    String summary = currently.getString("summary");
    double temperature = currently.getDouble("temperature");
    String icon = currently.getString("icon");

    LatLng latLngo = new LatLng(la,lon);
    ter.add(latLngo);
    weatherInfo.add(icon);

    // Now initiate the next call
    i++;
    if(i < arrayLis.size()) getItAgain();

    Log.i("LETSCHECK",""+la+", "+lon +icon);
}

public void getItAgain() {
    // Just start the first task without the loop. 
    double latitude = ((LatLng)arrayLis.get(i)).latitude;
    double longitude = ((LatLng)arrayLis.get(i)).longitude;
    String url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/"
            +latitude+","+longitude+"?units=si";
    LatLng mylatlng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    startProcess(url,mylatlng);
}
```

**Update**

I do not understand why it is showing 2 instead of 4 results. However, I think you need to modify the code as follows.

```
private void getCurrentDetails(String data,LatLng myLatlng) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject main = new JSONObject(data);
    double la = main.getDouble("latitude");
    double lon = main.getDouble("longitude");
    JSONObject currently = main.getJSONObject("currently");
    String summary = currently.getString("summary");
    double temperature = currently.getDouble("temperature");
    String icon = currently.getString("icon");

    // Move this upto here
    weatherInfo.add(icon);

    loopi++;
    Log.i("LETSCHECK",""+loopi);
    if (loopi < arrayList.size()) {
        getItAgain();
    } else {
        for (String l:weatherInfo) {
            Log.i("LETSCHECK",l); 
            //expected 4 items to show but its showing only 2 items
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Reaz thanks for your help, let me try it and I will let you know

Comment: Should I shift this entire code to IntentService class so that it will not block the entire main UI

Comment: No, it's not blocking the main UI thread. This is already asynchronous. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Hi, I have used your solution and it's working great but there is another problem please have a look into my EDIT section

Comment: yes sure, but can you please look into the above problem

Comment: Please see the update of my answer as well and let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are running asynchronous code, and the reason that their callbacks are not returning one after the other is logical since each HTTP call takes some amount of time, unrelated to the others, so the response for your third call might actually be received before the first one.

You can either use RxJava (and its operators), or improve the current code. For your `startProcess`, pass the `i` from your for-loop as the index and create an array outside of our function. Whenever you get a response from the server, you can store it in the `i`th position of your array. After each call you can check If all values have been fetched (by a counter or something). It is much better to move all this stuff to its own class so its contained and testable.

One thing to note is how you are gonna handle errors, because your calls might not be received successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code. After each success call remove the current proceed item from the array and do a another API request.

```
private void startProcess(ArrayList<LatLong> elementList){
LatLong myLatlng = elementList.get(0);
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(myurl)
        .build();
Call call  = httpClient.newCall(request);
call.enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

        String data = response.body().string();
        Log.i("DATASS",data);
        if (response.isSuccessful()){
            try {
                getCurrentDetails(data,myLatlng);
                elementList.remove(0)
                startProcess(elementList)
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }

});
```

}

Comment: hi, Thanks for posting the code, I have already tried another solution and its working great.